# How to limit the download speed and scheduling of Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS) jobs from code?

Tags: windows, delphi, download, microsoft-bits, bits-service

I'm trying to figure out how I can do the following stuff from code:

1. Limit the download speed of BITS jobs.
2. Limiting the downloading of BITS jobs to certain hours of the day.

I'm aware that you control this through group policies, but I'm trying to figure out if I can control it from the code, because my client IT team doesn't want to deal with setting group policies.

My current BITS client is written in Delphi, but if you have example code in C# or C++ that will be great as well.

I would appreciate your assistance.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you need management to talk sense into IT since it will surely be much simpler to do this with GP

Comment: Another point you might want to make: five years from now, when they're trying to figure out why (for example) Windows Update only downloads content at certain times of day, it'll be easy to figure out if group policy is doing it (or if they configured it by hand, for that matter) but difficult or impossible if it's the side-effect of an application.

Comment: The reason that we started using BITS, is because our client IT team doesn't want to touch anything that has to do with our application. It's kind of a inner company power struggle that has noting to do with us. I have to find a way to do this through code, otherwise I'll need to use a BITS replacement which would be a shame, because I'll need to rewrite a lot of code. Do you have any suggestions to such a BITS replacement?

Comment: [netlimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

- Open Group Policy by entering gpedit.msc /gpcomputer:"" in the Run window or at the command prompt in an MS-DOS window.
- BITS policies are located under Computer Configuration, Administrative Templates, Network, Background Intelligent Transfer Service.
- Right-click the policy and select Properties.
- Follow the directions for enabling and setting the policy.

Here you can find options how to throttling brandwith.